# UI alignment Testing in iOS

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

I am unit testing UI elements on iOS using the native XCTest framework. The limitation which I found is that we **cannot test the alignment of UI objects on screen**. Is there any third party framework which can help achieving this functionality. Please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative is `EarlGrey` or you can try `Appium`:
https://www2.smartbear.com/bitbar-beginner-guide-appium-mobile-app-testing.html

or you can try `Detox`:
https://bitbar.com/blog/automate-detox-mobile-tests-on-real-devices-in-the-cloud

or you can try `Calabash`:
https://www2.smartbear.com/bitbar-calabash-101.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rithik, I would look into these.